# Start wifi in adhoc mode right after boot

Tags: wireless, startup, init, adhoc

I'm trying to set my wireless card to adhoc mode after the system starts. I have created a shell script following this guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc#Wireless_Extensions_CLI_tools_Method

If I execute the script manually, everything works fine.
However if I add it to the init.d as described here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto#Installing_custom_init-scripts

or if I set it as a cron job triggered at "@reboot", the wireless interface doesn't seem to start.

I'm guessing that I can configure the card to start directly into the adhoc mode with /etc/network but I don't really know how.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/AdHoc) you add wireless-mode ad-hoc to your interface definition

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 1
    wireless-essid MYNETWORK
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```